# SWT Issue with Display settings of Windows

Tags: eclipse, swt

I have a fixed shell sized (800x600) application developed in SWT. The issue is, if I change the display settings of Windows ( from smaller - to medium/larger ) few parts of the application are being truncated.
So is there any way I can give dynamic size based on the selection of display settings ?

Comment: Do you want to keep the fixed application size?  Second, which layout are you using?  Third, which objects are not resizing properly?

Comment: Yes I want the application to be of fixed size. and this application consists of multiple composites inside the grid layout and all the composites also have grid layout.
I have the issue with the text and textboxes etc

Answer (score 0):

A fixed shell size is very seldom the right way to go. Instead, use the layout to set the constraints and let SWT figure out the size. That will make it more likely that dpi changes will work correctly and more likely that the app will look correct on other operating systems or different versions of Windows.

Comment: I am enhancing an already developed Installer application. So now I cannot change it from fixed now. I actually found this accidentally. My application has multiple composites on a single shell. 

Everything is looking good. But its only when we change the Display setting in Windows (Make Text items larger or smaller). The text in all the composites are increasing and going out of view

Comment: Can't have it both ways. Fixed size and smart scaling across a range of dpi settings aren't compatible.